# Hide UI element: Shiny app crashes when UI element is placed under taglist

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a simple shiny app and trying to hide and show elements using shinyjs(). I have attached the screenshots that show the UI for the first and second page along with input IDs for each element. The radio button "First page" should display all elements of "firstUI" and the "Second page" should display all the elements of "secondUI".

| "firstUI" | "secondUI" |
| --- | --- |
| selectizeInput("two vars") | sliderInput("num1") |
| Inline fluidRow (Output("temp_num") and selectInput("units_temp") | sliderInput("num2") |

"temp_out" renders an interactive slider and numeric input. Changing one , changes the other.The units dropdown converts the units of the entered value. 0F, 0C, K and R are the 4 temperature units I have used here. and their conversions are written inside functions Here is a screeshot of the app:
[image]

[image]

The problem I have is with this code block.

```
fluidRow(
        uiOutput("temp_out"),
        column(3,
               selectInput("units_temp", "Units", choices = c("K", "C", "F", "R"), selected = "K")
        )
      )
```

If the above  code block is inside taglist() of output$firstUI in server.R, as in my example below, the app crashes and I get an error:

Error in switch: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

The reason I want it inside "firstUI" is becasue I want to hide the elements when "Second page" is clicked. If the same block of code is under ui.R separately,(which I have commented) the app runs, but as expected, it is not hidden when "Second page" is clicked.

I don't understand what the the error is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Here is my code

```
#Unit conversion to Kelvin from a temerature unit
to_Kelvin <- function(value, unit){ # to SI (Kelvin)
  switch(unit,
         "K" = value,
         "C" = value + 273.15,
         "F" = (value -32) * (5 / 9) + 273.15,
         "R" = value * 5 / 9)
  }

#Unit conversion from a temperature unit to Kelvin
from_Kelvin <- function(value, unit){# from SI (Kelvin)
  switch(unit,
         "K" =  value,
         "C" =  value - 273.15,
         "F" = (value - 273.15) * (9 / 5) + 32,
         "R" =  value * 9 / 5)
  }

# INPUTS
#parameters
parms <- list("Temperature"    = "temp")

#slider range
range <- list("temp"    = c(100, 500))

# / INPUTS
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(title = "Shinyjs() example"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons('pageID', label = NULL,choices =  c('First page'='first', 'Second page'='second'), selected = 'first' ,inline = T),
      HTML(
        '<style>.col-sm-3, .col-sm-4 {
                padding-left: 2px;
                padding-right: 2px;
                }
             </style>'),
      
      uiOutput('firstUI'),
      
      # fluidRow(
      #   uiOutput("temp_out"),
      #   column(3,
      #          selectInput("units_temp", "Units", choices = c("K", "C", "F", "R"), selected = "K")
      #   )
      # ),
      # 
      hidden(uiOutput('secondUI'))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
              textOutput("text")
               )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  vls <- reactiveValues(previous_units = NULL, cur_temp = NA)

  render_slider <- reactive({

    f1 <- function(input_id, input_idnum, name, min, max, cur_val = NA){

      set_val <- (min + max) / 2
      if (! is.na(cur_val) && ! is.null(cur_val)) {
        print(paste('setting', cur_val))
        set_val <- as.numeric(cur_val)
      }
      ans <- list(column(width = 6, sliderInput((input_id), name, min = min, max = max, value = set_val, step = 0.00001)),
                  column(width = 3, numericInput(paste0(input_idnum), "Value", min = min, max = max, step = 0.00001, value = set_val))
      )
      return(ans)
    }

    return(f1)

  })

  rs <- reactive({

   list(
      "temp" = from_Kelvin(range$temp, input$units_temp)
   )
    
    })
  
  observeEvent(input[["temp"]],{
    
    vls[["cur_temp"]] <- as.numeric(input[["temp"]])
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["units_temp"]],{
    
    vls[["cur_temp"]] <- from_Kelvin (to_Kelvin (input[["temp"]], vls$previous_units["temp"]), input[["units_temp"]])
    
    vls$previous_units["temp"] = input[["units_temp"]]
    
  }, ignoreNULL = T, ignoreInit = T)

  observeEvent(input[["temp_num"]],{
    
    vls[["cur_temp"]] <- as.numeric(input[["temp_num"]])
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    if(is.null(vls$previous_units["temp"]) || is.na(vls$previous_units["temp"])){
      print('unitssss')
      
      vls$previous_units["temp"] = input[["units_temp"]]
      print(vls$previous_units["temp"])
    }
  })
  
  
  output$temp_out <- renderUI({
    
    render_slider()("temp", "temp_num", "Temperature", min(rs()$temp), max(rs()$temp), vls$cur_temp) 
    
  })
  
  output$firstUI <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectizeInput("two_vars",
                     "Select two variables",
                    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F"),
                     selected=c("A", "B"),
                     multiple=T,
                     options = list(maxItems = 2)
       ),
    
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput("temp_out"),
        column(3,
               selectInput("units_temp", "Units", choices = c("K", "C", "F", "R"), selected = "K")
        )
      )

    )
  })
  
  output$secondUI<-renderUI({
    div(
      
      sliderInput(
        "num1",
        "Enter number 1 ",
        1,8,1
      ),
      
      sliderInput(
        "num2",
        "Enter number 2",
        1,8,1
      )
      
      
    )
      
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$pageID,{
    if(input$pageID == 'first'){
      
      shinyjs::hide('secondUI')
      shinyjs::show('firstUI')
      
      } else {
        
      shinyjs::show('secondUI')
      shinyjs::hide('firstUI')

    }
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
  
  paste("Temperature is", vls$cur_temp, input$units_temp, sep=" ")
})
  
}

# create a shiny app
shinyApp(ui=ui,
         server=server)
```

Comment: Can you use `conditionPanel()` to display certain elements when the appropriate selection of radioButton is done?

Comment: I tried using the conditional panel, still doesn't work. Again the error seems in the fluidRow block. If I remove the block, the condition works. I cant figure out what the error is 


      conditionalPanel(condition =
                         "input.pageID == 'first'",
                       uiOutput('firstUI')),


      conditionalPanel(condition =
                         "input.pageID == 'second'",
                       uiOutput('secondUI'))

Answer (score 0):

You have created a interdependency and that will not work.  You have reactive objects `rs` and `vls` depending on `units_temp`, but that cannot be rendered/defined in the same renderUI as it requires the same reactive objects.

If you change your `render_slider()` call to the following it works:

```
render_slider()("temp", "temp_num", "Temperature", min(range$temp), max(range$temp), 300)
```

To keep your current `render_slider()` call, define the `selectInput` for `units_temp` in a separate `renderUI` and it will work.

Full working code is below.  You can update it to make it work with the reactive object `vls`, and space between different items in ui - as you are also using HTML code.

```
# INPUTS
#parameters
parms <- list("Temperature"    = "temp")

#slider range
range <- list("temp"    = c(100, 500))

# / INPUTS
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  # Application title
  titlePanel(title = "Shinyjs() example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons('pageID', label = NULL,choices =  c('First page'='first', 'Second page'='second'), selected = 'first' ,inline = T),
      HTML(
        '<style>.col-sm-3, .col-sm-4 {
                padding-left: 2px;
                padding-right: 2px;
                }
             </style>'),

      uiOutput('firstUI'),

      # fluidRow(
      #   uiOutput("temp_out"),
      #   column(3,
      #          selectInput("units_temp", "Units", choices = c("K", "C", "F", "R"), selected = "K")
      #   )
      # ),
      #
      hidden(uiOutput('secondUI'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               textOutput("text")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  vls <- reactiveValues(previous_units = NULL, cur_temp = NA)

  render_slider <- reactive({

    f1 <- function(input_id, input_idnum, name, min, max, cur_val = NA){

      set_val <- (min + max) / 2
      if (! is.na(cur_val) && ! is.null(cur_val)) {
        print(paste('setting', cur_val))
        set_val <- as.numeric(cur_val)
      }
      ans <- list(column(width = 6, sliderInput((input_id), name, min = min, max = max, value = set_val, step = 0.00001)),
                  column(width = 3, numericInput(paste0(input_idnum), "Value", min = min, max = max, step = 0.00001, value = set_val))
      )
      return(ans)
    }

    return(f1)

  })

  rs <- reactive({
    req(input$units_temp)
    list(
      "temp" = from_Kelvin(range$temp, input$units_temp)
    )

  })

  # observeEvent(input[["temp"]],{
  #
  #   vls[["cur_temp"]] <- as.numeric(input[["temp"]])
  #
  # })
  #
  # observeEvent(input[["units_temp"]],{
  #
  #   vls[["cur_temp"]] <- from_Kelvin (to_Kelvin (input[["temp"]], vls$previous_units["temp"]), input[["units_temp"]])
  #
  #   vls$previous_units["temp"] = input[["units_temp"]]
  #
  # }, ignoreNULL = T, ignoreInit = T)
  #
  # observeEvent(input[["temp_num"]],{
  #
  #   vls[["cur_temp"]] <- as.numeric(input[["temp_num"]])
  #
  # })
  #
  # observe({
  #
  #   if(is.null(vls$previous_units["temp"]) || is.na(vls$previous_units["temp"])){
  #     print('unitssss')
  #
  #     vls$previous_units["temp"] = input[["units_temp"]]
  #     print(vls$previous_units["temp"])
  #   }
  # })
  #
  #
  output$temp_out <- renderUI({

    render_slider()("temp", "temp_num", "Temperature", min(rs()$temp), max(rs()$temp), vls$cur_temp)
    #render_slider()("temp", "temp_num", "Temperature", min(range$temp), max(range$temp), 300)

  })

  output$temp_out2 <- renderUI({

    selectInput("units_temp", "Units", choices = c("K", "C", "F", "R"), selected = "K", width=50)

  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    #paste("Temperature is", vls$cur_temp, input$units_temp, sep=" ")
    paste("Temperature is", min(rs()$temp), "-", max(rs()$temp) , sep=" ")

  })

  output$firstUI <- renderUI({
    #req(rs(),render_slider())
    tagList(
      selectizeInput("two_vars",
                     "Select two variables",
                     c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F"),
                     selected=c("A", "B"),
                     multiple=T,
                     options = list(maxItems = 2)
      ),

      fluidRow(
        column(10,uiOutput("temp_out")), column(2,uiOutput("temp_out2"))
        #column(3, selectInput("units_temp", "Units", choices = c("K", "C", "F", "R"), selected = "K") )
      )

    )
  })

  output$secondUI<-renderUI({
    div(

      sliderInput(
        "num1",
        "Enter number 1 ",
        1,8,1
      ),

      sliderInput(
        "num2",
        "Enter number 2",
        1,8,1
      )
    )

  })

  observeEvent(input$pageID,{
    if(input$pageID == 'first'){

      shinyjs::hide('secondUI')
      shinyjs::show('firstUI')

    } else {

      shinyjs::show('secondUI')
      shinyjs::hide('firstUI')

    }
  })

  # output$text <- renderText({
  #
  #   paste("Temperature is", vls$cur_temp, input$units_temp, sep=" ")
  # })

}

# create a shiny app
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I tried that by creating another  renderUI() as you mentioned and getting the same error.
firstUI contains taglist of selectizeInput and fluidRow(uiOutput("temp_out")).
firstUI_add  contains taglist of  fluidRow(
        column(3,
               selectInput("units_temp", ...).

In the conditionalPanel(), I added  uiOutput("firstUI ") and uiOutput("firstUI_add") for first page selection. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried. Seems like the observeEvents() are commented? The app runs, but I want the numeric and slider to react to one another. If I set 400 in slider, the numeric should read 400. If I set 200 in numeric, the slider should shift to 200. Also, the range in the slider should change to right scale when temp units are changed from say F to C. That is why I have those observeEvents. vls$cur_temp is set depending on what is triggered as well as the units that are selected.

Comment: I tried uncommenting observeEvent(input[["temp"]] and observeEvent(input[["temp_num"]]. It works, but the units are changed, from say K to C, the slider pointer shifts to the extreme right. Would like the slider in the same position , and that is why I had the observeEvent(input[["units_temp"]] . When I uncomment this, I get the same error

Comment: if you comment out `observeEvent(input[["temp_num"]]...})`, most of your code works as expected.  This observer may need some work.

Comment: Please note that the question in this OP was about hide/display of firstUI/secondUI.  I think that has been answered.  Your observer issue is a separate one and you should post a separate question specific to that issue. Someone can help you on that question.